# Error: Cannot find module 'src/utils/validateRegister'

Tags: typescript

Im currently getting this error when I try to use my util function. I also posted my folder structure in case it helps.

Im able to import the module but for some reason when I run yarn dev it tells me that it connot find the module.

[image: Here is the error that im getting]

[image]

Comment: please show the import string

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

It was auto importing in the format `import { validateRegister } from "src/utils/validateRegister";`

but I needed to change it to `import { validateRegister } from "../utils/validateRegister";`

I then deleted the dist folder and ran my yarn dev script.